# ajax parameter to c# websevice

Tags: c#, ajax, parameters

I have a webservice function HellowWorld(string str), and I want to call it in js. How can I pass the parameter into HelloWorld from js? My code is below. Thanks a lot.

//code in js

```
function BindJson() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'Service1.asmx?op=HelloWorld',

        data: {str: 'asdasdas'},

        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data1) {
            alert('suc    ' + data1.d);
        },
        error: function (request, status, errorThrown) {
            alert('err    ' + status + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    BindJson();    
});
```

//code in c# webservice

```
[WebMethod]
        public void HelloWorld(string str)
        {
            StreamWriter _testData = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/data.txt"), true);
            _testData.WriteLine(str); // Write the file.
            _testData.Flush();
            _testData.Close(); // Close the instance of StreamWriter.
            _testData.Dispose(); // Dispose from memory.       
        }
```

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738097/jquery-ajax-with-json-call-to-wcf-service-pass-through-to-wcf-service) once, It might help..

Comment: Try with Post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188315/javascript-array-as-wcf-webservice-parameter

Comment: First thanks all of you. And I have tried all what you told me, but none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

?op= is operational parameter for testing webservice through browser you can go with 'Service1.asmx/HelloWorld' instead of Service1.asmx/?op= HelloWorld

Comment: I have tried this but get the message "Internal Server Error" which means occurring the error: function.